# How can you have SharePoint Link Lists default to opening in a new window?

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

In SharePoint, it is easy to set up a List webpart consisting of Links to other documents, folders, sites, etc.  Unfortunately, when clicking these links, the default behavior is for the page to open in the current browser window.  That is, it does NOT open the page in a new instance of the browser.  This has proven annoying for a number of the users on my site.

Does anyone know of a way to have the default behavior be to open in a NEW browser window?

I'm hoping this is something that can be set in SharePoint rather than having users need to adjust some sort of setting in their browser.

Comment: Please think long and hard before doing this. Opening new windows usually violates the principle of least surprise for the user, and doesn't really achieve what people are usually hoping to do by popping a new window (i.e. they don't really "stick" to your original site any better just because it's sitting in a now-hidden window behind the one you popped up). Also, the solution would probably be different depneding on your version of SharePoint. You may want to edit to the question to indicate WSS 2/3, SPS, MOSS, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible with the default Link List web part, but there are resources describing how to extend Sharepoint server-side to add this functionality.

[Share Point Links Open in New Window](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/articles/SharepointLinksListOpenInNewWindow.aspx)
[Changing Link Lists in Sharepoint 2007](http://weblogs.asp.net/bryanglass/archive/2008/03/07/changing-links-list-in-sharepoint-2007-to-open-in-new-browser-window.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You can edit the page in SharePoint designer, convert the List View web part to an XSLT Data View. (by right click + "Convert to XSLT Data View").
Then you can edit the XSLT - find the `A` tag and add an attribute `target="_blank"`

Comment: Good call, didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

The same instance for SP2010; the Links List webpart will not automatically open in a new window, rather user must manually rt click Link object and select Open in New Window.

The add/ insert Link option withkin SP2010 will allow a user to manually configure the link to open in a new window.

Maybe SP2012 release will adrress this...

Answer (score 0):

Under the Links Tab ==> Edit the URL Item ==> Under the URL (Type the Web address)- format the value as follows:

Example:
if the URL = http://www.abc.com ==> then suffix the value with ==>

- #openinnewwindow/,'" target="http://www.abc.com'

SO, the final value should read as ==>
http://www.abc.com#openinnewwindow/,'" target="http://www.abc.com'

DONE ==> this will open the URL in New Window

Comment: This doesn't seem to work at all. SharePoint just changes the link to the value without the suffix after I save the page.